# How can I reset to a commit and make it master?

Tags: git, github, git-revert

I would like to reset m repository to an old commit and start tracking the changes from there. It is like 50 commits ago, so git revert is not an option. What should I do?

P.S. update - I also need to push that commit and become the last commit in the repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to a previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Comment: Joe If i use the method above - I will have to write all the 50 commit SHA manually...

Comment: I don't believe you understood the answers in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git reset --hard <commit-hash-of-commit-to-reset-to>
```

Be aware this will remove all changes since then, if you want to keep the changes and just remove the commits, use `--soft` instead of hard

Comment: `git reset --soft` [won't update the index](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) so all changes will be staged after the reset is complete. If you want to keep the changes _only_ in your working copy (and not the index) use `git reset --mixed` or simply `git reset`.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is correct. I am adding few more information I have found on http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

```
$ git commit ...              (1)
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1     (2)
<< edit files as necessary >> (3)
$ git add ....                (4)
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD     (5)
```

> (1) This is what you want to undo
>
> (2) This is most often done when you remembered what you just
>   committed is incomplete, or you misspelled your commit message1, or
>   both. Leaves working tree as it was before "commit".
>
> (3) Make corrections to working tree files.
>
> (4) Stage changes for commit.
>
> (5) Commit the changes, reusing the old commit message. reset copied
>   the old head to `.git/ORIG_HEAD`; commit with `-c ORIG_HEAD` will open an
>   editor, which initially contains the log message from the old commit
>   and allows you to edit it. If you do not need to edit the message, you
>   could use the `-C` option instead.